# Material Ui Automcomplete Clear icon style

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I want to change the color of the clear icon, I have tried [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-custom-endadornment-86c87?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js:1342-1356) but it removes the icon with a static one. I just want to change the color.

[image]

```js
        <Autocomplete className={`${commonClasses.searchBarMobileScreen}`}
          id="product-search"
          forcePopupIcon={false}
          classes={searchTextColor()}
          options={options.sort((a, b) => -b.name.localeCompare(a.name))}
          groupBy={(option) => option.cid}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => (`${option.brand} ${option.name}`)}
          renderInput={(params) => <SearchTextField
            fullWidth
            {...params}
            label="Search..."
            variant="outlined"
            InputLabelProps={{
              classes: {
                root: commonClasses.whiteColor,
              }
            }}
          />}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some styles to the clearIndicator. The global class is `.MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator`

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  inputRoot: {
    color: "blue",
    fontFamily: "Roboto Mono",
    backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: "2px",
      borderColor: "blue"
    },
    "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: "2px",
      borderColor: "blue"
    },
    "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: "2px",
      borderColor: "blue"
    }
  },
  clearIndicator: {
    color: "red"
  }
}));

export default function ComboBox() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      classes={classes}
      options={[1,2,3]}
      forcePopupIcon
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer it works ! how do you find the global class name ?

Comment: You're welcome. You can check it there https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api in the CSS section but can also find it with the Inspect Element browser tools ;)